# Show my tag stats, badge progress on the tag page

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, user-interface

My profile [tells me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17875/eevee?tab=tags&sort=votes) that I've answered 81 questions tagged as `python` and accumulated 355 votes from them.

But this doesn't appear anywhere on the [`python` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info).  Nor does it mention that I have the bronze badge for `python`.  It *does* show my progress towards Research Assistant, which is a little out of place, given it's the only thing in the sidebar not specific to the tag I'm looking at.

It took some hunting to find out that my stats do appear on the tag's topusers, since I'm not a top user and never even thought to look there.  :)  That doesn't show badge progress, though, and I admit I'm enamored with the tiny badge progress bar on review queues.  Can we get one for tags?